# How to tell Visual Studio's static analyzer that a function validates a precondition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have to admit I appreciate the effort the Visual Studio static code analyzer does. It has found some issues in my C/C++ code that could, under certain circumstances, lead to some unusual bugs.

However, there are some other places where it finds issues that I have already prepared for.

Take for instance something like this: I have a C array, with a static size somewhere:

```
static const int DataSize = 100;
int Data[DataSize];
```

...and then I have a method or function that accesses this data:

```
void DoSomething(size_t index)
{
    if (index >= DataSize)
        Panic("Out of bounds");
    Data[index] = DoSomethingElse();
}
```

This `Panic()` function is meant to notify me when the precondition is not met, and points to an error that can't be recovered from. In a debug build, it breaks into the debugger so I can analyze what happened, while in a release build, it will intentionally crash the program, leaving some useful debug information.

However, if I compile this, Visual Studio 2019 gives me the following warning:

> Warning C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'Data':  the writable size is '400' bytes, but 'index' bytes might be written.

The warning is indeed valid, if I were not performing the precondition check just before.

One way to suppress this warning is by changing the code to something like:

```
void DoSomething(size_t index)
{
    if (index >= DataSize)
    {
        Panic("Out of bounds");
        return; // This is never reached...
    }
    Data[index] = DoSomethingElse();
}
```

But, not only this is unnecessarily verbose, it also may confuse the static code analyzer even more, because it can make it think that returning is a valid code path, further confusing it.

Another example, this time unrelated to arrays, and applicable to C and C++. Consider a function or method like this:

```
int DoSomeOperation(int operationType, int value)
{
    int foo;
    switch (operationType)
    {
    case 0:
        foo = 10;
        break;
    case 1:
        foo = value + 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        foo = value - 1;
        break;
    // ... many more cases
    default:
        Panic("Invalid operationType");
        // We never reach this line...
    }

    DoSomeOtherOperation(foo);
}
```

This raises the following warning in the `DoSomeOtherOperation()` line:

> Warning C6001: Using uninitialized memory 'foo'.

Once again, I can either explicitly initialize `foo`, initialize it to something in the `default` case, or return from the function after `Panic()`, but technically, neither is necessary, since for all semantically valid values of `operationType`, `foo` is indeed initialized.

In fact, I might prefer to leave `foo` uninitialized at the beginning, so the static analyzer -does- catch a case where I did indeed missed the initialization.

Now, is there a way to annotate the `Panic` function, so the static code analyzer knows that this function will validate the precondition, or alternatively, that it terminates the program in all cases, so it doesn't have to consider the case where the function returns and the program continues?

Comment: If `Panic` throws an exception, could you just define `Panic` as a type which takes a string argument, then throw that, so your code would be `throw Panic("Out of bounds");`. Would that result in the same code, and the static analyser should be happier with that

Comment: Is this C++ or C? These are two different languages with two different approaches to handling this. By the `this->` part I presume C++.

Comment: @tadman: The code is compiled as C++, but uses a lot of C style code, like static arrays, instead of std::vector. Either the C or the C++ approach are available to me.

Comment: If it has even a pinch of C++ in it, a C compiler cannot deal and it's a C++ question. It's understood that C++ questions can and will contain C-style code, but it's a special form that takes into account C++ restrictions and rules. For example, C flat out does not have exceptions. People looking to answer C questions won't be able to help you with that.

Comment: The next question is why you're doing this. Is it an assignment or academic exercise to understand, or is the actual goal bounds-checking? If it's just bounds checking, [`std::vector` already has it in the form of `at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) which is where you should start. If it's an exercise, there's several other considerations to explore here.

Comment: @tadman: It is production code. Please understand that I'm not very interested in long discussions on whether I should change my entire code base to use C++ vectors instead of C style arrays. It seems like you know the exact answer for both C and C++; if you do, I'd appreciate it if you share it.

Comment: I'm not saying your entire code base, I'm saying *this* code. It doesn't have to exist. You're just re-implementing `at()`. It already solves this problem. C solutions basically boil down to "slap `assert()` all over the place and hope for the best" which is why I'm not even going to touch C.

Comment: @tadman: Apologies for the misunderstanding. The code I posted in the question is a minimal sample code that can trigger the warning I described, but the snippet as-is is not in the actual code. I am getting this warning in dozens to hundreds of places which are doing stuff similar to this, including work on C-compatible external APIs that already use C-style arrays. I don't think the context behind each instance of this warning is very useful to other people who may experience the same problem, so I made an artificial snippet to illustrate the issue. That's also why I used the C tag.

Comment: That's the contradiction here. If you want a C solution, you can't use C++. You can't use exceptions, or anything like that. If you want a C++ solution that's C-flavored, well, that's not how C++ rolls, so you'll need to bang together what will end up being a poor imitation of what `at()` already does comprehensively.

Comment: Depending on the VCC checks to save you from out of bounds errors should really be a last resort. Where these conditions exist you need a better solution than popping exceptions using custom code.

Comment: If you're doing something *really* bizarre here like making code that can be compiled in C or C++ and work in two completely different ways then the only approach I can think of is if you have a macro that figures it out and writes the appropriate `Panic()` code, but I still think that's a bad idea.

Comment: @tadman: Even though it seems like it is all about arrays, it is actually not. There are other types of false-positive warnings, where the static analyzer doesn't understand that I'm actually indeed checking for the precondition. I've added another example, which is unrelated to arrays/vectors, and is valid in C and C++. If you're okay with it, I'd like to add the C tag to the question back.

Comment: @Tas: I tried throwing from inside `Panic()`, but the static analyzer still believes that execution can continue after `Panic()`. What's the difference with throwing at the call instead of inside `Panic()`?

Comment: If the `Panic` function always terminates the program or throws an exception then perhaps you should declare it with `[[noreturn]]` attribute, preventing the compiler from considering unreachable code paths. Also, in your first example, you check `if (index > DataSize)`, but what about the case when `index == DataSize`? Assigning to `Data[DataSize]` would still be out of bounds then.

Comment: @heapunderrun: I'll try `[[noreturn]]`. However, `Panic()` always ends with `exit(1)`, which in principle is `[[noreturn]]` though... As for the condition, apologies -- the synthetic sample I made was indeed wrong. I fixed it now.

Comment: @heapunderrun: unfortunately [[noreturn]] didn't change anything. I'll keep it in `Panic()` though. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any way to tell the analyzer that a parameter is checked in the code but isn't this a job exactly for the *In_range*(low, hi) annotation?

Change the declaration to the following and the analyzer should be able to check the precondition (So long as it picks up the values of static like DataSize in this example, I am not sure whether it does or not).

```
void DoSomething(_In_range_(0, DataSize)
```

SAL is described at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/using-sal-annotations-to-reduce-c-cpp-code-defects?view=msvc-160

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'll take a look at the annotations. Do you know if they are standard? The code should compile on Windows, as well as some other platforms (it's a game framework). I can put some platform dependent code guarded with #defines, but doing it for every function is a bit impractical. I'll try it tonight though.